# How configure packages.config to download the highest version

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I want to configure packages.config to download the available highest version of a package. How can I do that?

Something like:

```
<package id="PackageName" version="Highest" ... />
```

I saw attr "allowedVersions", but it always download the version configured in "version" attr.

Comment: Are you sure? Don't you want to test whether a new version of a package doesn't break your code first?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. No, I control the package. I just want the last version.

Comment: Not possible with a packages.config file. You could try a floating PackageReference version - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution#floating-versions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How configure packages.config to download the highest version

Just as Ashley and Matt said, it is impossible to do that, because `packages.config` only allows a single version of a package to be specified.

The simple workaround is using nuget cli to update that package in the pre-build event:

```
$(YourNuGetPath)\nuget.exe update "$(ProjectDir)packages.config" -Id "<YourPackageId>"
```

With this build event, Visual Studio will update that package to the latest version before you build your project.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible with NuGet it only allows specific versions. The `allowedVersions` is used to block someone from going beyond *or below* a specific version. i.e. version 1.* is fine but you cannot go to version 2.0.

A typical workaround for something like this is a batch/powershells script which updates the package you want. You could then hook this into a pre-build.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use PackageReference node directly in the project file now.
By doing so you can define a floating version that will select the highest stable version.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#version-ranges